# How to stop on first items failure FluentValidation RuleForEach

Tags: .net-core, fluentvalidation

I have a nested collection property in my object. i need to make it stop on first failure for collection items. I mean error message should not be repetitive for each item for failures. Cascade is not works for this scenario. Thanks :)

My Object:

```
public class Customer{    
   public string CustomerName{get;set;}   
   public List<Order> Orders {get;set;} 
}

public class Order{
   public string OrderNumber{get;set;}
   public int Amount{get;set;}
}
```

Example Request:

```
{
    CustomerName="test",
    Orders:[
        {
            "OrderNumber":null,
            "Amount":0
        },
        {
            "OrderNumber":"",
            "Amount":null
        },
        {
            "OrderNumber":"12345",
            "Amount":0
        }
    ]
}
```

I use fluent validation for nested object like below. But when it runs the error messages are repetitive. It should be stop on first items failure.

Code:

```
this.RuleForEach(x => x.Orders).Cascade(CascadeMode = CascadeMode.Stop).SetValidator(new ShipmentListRequestItemValidator()));
```

Error output (actual):

```
"OrderNumber is null!", "OrderNumber is empty!", "Amount should be greater than 0"
```

Error output (should be):

```
"OrderNumber is null!"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can override ValidationResult to get first error .
like this :

```
    public override ValidationResult Validate(ValidationContext<TestEntity> context)
            {
                 List<ValidationFailure> mainErrors = new List<ValidationFailure>();
                 mainErrors.Add(base.Validate(context).Errors.FirstOrDefault());
                 return new ValidationResult(mainErrors);
            }
```